# Join subqueries to one another redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have three queries all form the same table. I want to combine them into one table.

The queries are as follows:

```
Select events1.committee_name, count(events1.eventid) AS "Events" 
from periscope_events_summary events1
group by events1.committee_name;

Select events2.committee_name, count(events2.eventsignupid) "Completed" 
from .periscope_events_summary events2 
where status = 'Completed'
group by committee_name;

Select events3.committee_name, count(events3.eventsignupid) "completed events" 
from periscope_events_summary events3 
where status = 'Completed' and events3.event_type = '1:1 Meeting'
group by events3.committee_name;
```

They are all from the same table in a Reshift database.

My ideal output is:

```
Commiteename Events 1:1 Completed
---------------------------------
name            #   #    #
Name 2          #   #    #
```

Each query works as desired but when I try to combine them I have gotten errors or the values are not correct. I have tried several joins and that hasn't worked. I have tried subqueries as columns that haven't worked wither. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

How about this. Which errors are you getting? I what way the data is not correct?

```
WITH events AS (
    SELECT committee_name,
           count(eventid) AS "Events"
    FROM periscope_events_summary
    GROUP BY 1
),completed AS (
         SELECT committee_name,
                count(eventsignupid) AS "Completed"
         FROM periscope_events_summary
         WHERE status = 'Completed'
         GROUP BY 1
),
completed_events AS (
    SELECT committee_name,
        count(eventsignupid) AS "completed events"
    FROM periscope_events_summary
    WHERE status = 'Completed'
    AND event_type = '1:1 Meeting'
    GROUP BY committee_name
)
SELECT 
    events.committee_name, 
    events."Events",
    completed."Completed",
    completed_events."completed events"
FROM events
LEFT JOIN completed USING (committee_name)
LEFT JOIN completed_events USING (committee_name)
```

Comment: Worked so very much. I am gonna try to understand the query. You took the queries and ran each one as a temp table and joined them all correct?

Comment: Why did you group by 1?

Comment: @MichaelIngram exactly - I used _common table expression_ for each table, and then joined them in the actual select. 

`GROUP BY 1` means _group by the first column in that table_. It comes in handy when you group by many columns, and you don't want to repeat their names. So it's equivalent to `GROUP BY committee_name`.